# Como actualizar varios registros php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bueno estoy haciendo una lista de asistencia y quiero actualizar de todas las personas en una sola vez. Me pase toda el día sin resolverlo.

Codigo de la vista

```
@extends('layouts.docen')
@section ('contenido')
```

```
<h3>Editar Asistencia</h3>
@if (count($errors)>0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
</div>
```

{!!Form::model($CursoProgramado,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>
   ['asistencia.update',$CursoProgramado->idAsistencia]])!!}
        {{Form::token()}}

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-reponsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>Alumno</th>
                    <th>Asistencia</th>
                </thead>

                <tr>
    @foreach($asistenciass as $reg)
                    <td>{{$reg->nombres}} {{$reg->apellidos_pat}} {{$reg->apellidos_mat}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="idAsistencia[]" value="{{$reg->idAsistencia}}">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="asistencia[]" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="A" >Asistió</option>
                                        <option value="T" >Tarde</option>
                                        <option value="F">Falta</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    @endforeach 
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset">Limpiar</button>

        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
 @endsection
```

Controller

```
public function update(AlumnoFormRequest $request)
{
    foreach ($request->get('asistencia') as $key => $value) {
        $asistencia->idAsistencia = $request->get('idAsistencia')[$key];;
        $asistencia->asistencia = $value;
        $asistencia->idCursoProg = $request->get('idCursoProg')[$key];
        $asistencia->IdRegistro = $request->get('IdRegistro')[$key];
        $asistencia->update();
    }
    return Redirect::to('asistencia');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes un objeto sobre el que trabajar.

En el caso de nuevos registros:

```
$asistencia = new Asistencia;
```

Con registros ya existentes:

```
$asistencia = Asistencia::find($request->get('idAsistencia')[$key]);
```

Y el controlador quedará así:

```
public function update(AlumnoFormRequest $request)
{
    foreach ($request->get('asistencia') as $key => $value) {
        $asistencia = Asistencia::find($request->get('idAsistencia')[$key]);
        $asistencia->idAsistencia = $request->get('idAsistencia')[$key];
        $asistencia->asistencia = $value;
        $asistencia->idCursoProg = $request->get('idCursoProg')[$key];
        $asistencia->IdRegistro = $request->get('IdRegistro')[$key];
        $asistencia->update();
    }
    return Redirect::to('asistencia');
}
```

Como parece que tu código para crear nuevos y actualizar existentes es el mismo, puedes usar `findOrCreate()` , que dejaría el controlador como sigue:

```
public function update(AlumnoFormRequest $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->get('asistencia') as $key => $value) {
            $asistencia = Asistencia::findOrCreate($request->get('idAsistencia')[$key]);
            $asistencia->idAsistencia = $request->get('idAsistencia')[$key];
            $asistencia->asistencia = $value;
            $asistencia->idCursoProg = $request->get('idCursoProg')[$key];
            $asistencia->IdRegistro = $request->get('IdRegistro')[$key];
            $asistencia->update();
        }
        return Redirect::to('asistencia');
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó.